# Split a string into indexes in a List of Lists

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a collection of text that I am trying to parse in order to audit against.  In Python3 I am trying to split the white space in a list of lists so that each word gets its own index and then add data that is missing to some of the lists .  Ex:

```
listoflists=[['Port UP UP Description'] , ['Port    Description' ],[ 'Port UP UP Description']]
```

I'd like to make it so that the output of listoflists now contains:

```
listoflists=[['Port,UP,UP,Description'] , ['Port, Down, Down, Description' ],[ 'Port,UP,UP,Description']]
```

My goal here is to then use this data to output to prettytable or something like that with rows containing each for indexes from each list and then, phase 2, audit against which rows have 'Ports' showing down.

I tried something like this but I believe my thinking is not quite right here.

```
for i in range(len(listoflists)):
    listoflists=i.split(' ')

for item in items:
    new_items.extend(item.split())
```

Comment: The question is pretty unclear and we don't know what platform you're coding on. Can you clean it up and add content so it makes sense? i.e. *now contains:* has nothing following it so we don't know what the expected output should be.

Comment: improve code output

Comment: Thanks for responding and sorry about that.  I think a bunch of my data was stripped when I hit submit and it asked me for tags.  Updated.

Comment: I think there's an error in your post because `['Port    Description' ]` turned into `['Port, Down, Down, Description' ]`. If I understood your question you would like to split the strings and then join them again with commas ?